# Illustrator expand command causes artefacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an issue with one of my artwork, every time I try to expand it, there is artefacts appearing randomly. Any idea where it could come from ? See images attached for reference

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Hi Piratoeuf, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get yourself up to speed with the Stack Exchange model and what is on and off topic here. Keep contributing and enjoy learning with all of us!

Answer (score 1):

This could basically be caused by anything. It may sound a bit jaded, but Illustrator, as good an app as it is, is also—ahem—a hot buggy mess. If you cannot find a possible cause in your original shape, it might just be one of those bugs rearing its ugly head.

In this case, I'd say it's possible that this artefact was caused by the original shape being a stroke and two anchors not connecting on the artefact's spot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vincent, I guess you're right... I will double check my strokes :)